# writng javascript in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

i am writing a javascript in selenium but it doesnt work .... here is my code

```
FluentJavascript variable = executeScript("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();", element); // to get x, y, width and height of element
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @john it is not compiled

Comment: OK, what doesn't compile? Also, I don't see how that line of code is relevant. Unless, say, you haven't imported `FluentJavascript` and thus the compiler doesn't know what to do with it or maybe `executeScript` has a different signature. Or erhaps `element` is never initialised. That's pure guessing here but the compiler should have told you pretty explicitly if either of these was the case. The JS definitely has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @mmmm there must always be a reason for compilation error, check its message/stacktrace.

Comment: Please paste the compilation error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve the size of an element and its position relative to the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) you can invoke the [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method as follows :

- Through *Java* you can use the *Dimension* class and invoke `getBoundingClientRect()` as follows :

  ```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));
  Dimension mydimension =  (Dimension) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();", element);
  ```
- Through *Javascript* you can invoke `getBoundingClientRect()` as follows :

  ```
  var rect = document.getElementById("myElement").getBoundingClientRect();
  ```

  This line will return the smallest rectangle which contains the entire element with *left*, *top*, *right*, *bottom*, *x*, *y*, *width* and *height* properties describing the overall border-box in pixels.

**Note** : The properties other than *width* and *height* are relative to the top-left corner of the viewport.

Comment: but i want to write it in java context (selenium to be to the point)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to find executeScript easier:

```
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();", element);
```

and also make sure element does exist.

Comment: For all we know, `executeScript` in OP's example might actually just be calling that eventually. We still don't know exactly what the error he has is and thus it's unknown if your replacement line would even work.